# Converting malloc() to SYS V Shared Memory w/ Multiple Processes

Tags: c, linux, malloc, shared-memory, huge-pages

I'm working on improving a program to utilize statically allocated huge pages in Linux rather than standard 4Kb pages. I've already set up a system with static huge page support and allocated a large amount of huge pages in the huge page pool (/prov/sys/vm/nr_hugepages). My hope now was to go through the program and find where large malloc()'s are taking place so I can remove the malloc() and replace it with a shmget/shmat which will have the SHM_HUGETLB flag set.

Keep in mind this is highly concurrent program.

My goal in using shared memory isn't to actually use the memory in a shared fashion. I want to preserve all the functions of the malloc() routine while just using statically allocated huge page support in its place.

Below is a sample code segment of what I'm trying to accomplish. Before the program reaches this point it has forked off a number of processes. Each process will be going through this segment of code concurrently. Originally this segment contained just the following code:

```
if( !( PANEL->WORK = (void *)malloc( (size_t)(lwork) *
                                   sizeof( double ) ) ) )
 {
    HPL_pabort( __LINE__, "HPL_pdpanel_init",
             "Memory allocation failed" );
 }
```

Which works fine.

Now I've modified that to this:

Note!!: I use a random number as a key so each process will have a random key identifying it's independent memory allocation.

```
int shmid1;
size_t dsize = (size_t)(lwork) * sizeof( double );

/*2097152 is 2MB or the huge page size, if memory request is less, 
  resort to standard malloc */
if( dsize < 2097152) {
  if( !( PANEL->WORK = (void *)malloc(dsize) ) )
  {
     HPL_pabort( __LINE__, "HPL_pdpanel_init",
                 "Memory allocation failed" );
  }
}
else {
  /* Get random number to use as a key */
  int randomData = open("/dev/random",O_RDONLY);
  int random;
  read(randomData, &random, sizeof(random));
  close(randomData);
  /* Get shared memory segment */
  shmid1 = shmget(random, dsize, SHM_HUGETLB
     | IPC_CREAT | SHM_R
     | SHM_W);
  if ( shmid1 < 0 ) {
  perror("shmget");
  exit(1);
  }
  printf("HugeTLB shmid: 0x%x\n", shmid1);
  PANEL->WORK = (void *)shmat(shmid1, 0, 0);
}
```

With this new implementation whenever I attempt to read from PANEL->WORK I get a segmentation fault. Before I really start digging into why this is segfaulting I can't help but wonder if I'm approaching this correctly. Is this the best way to approach this and does anyone see a mistake in this methodology?

Comment: I really don't think this is the right way to achieve what you want. `mmap` will automatically use huge pages if suitable, and `malloc` uses `mmap` directly for large allocations. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: My goal is to improve program performance. On my system, this segment of code typically allocates about 15gb of memory. The use of huge pages would hopefully improve application performance. I know it will because I've had measurable improvements in the application using transparent huge pages. I want to see if I can get a larger improvement with this static allocated pages. My understanding is mmap will only use huge pages on a mounted hugetlbfs filesystem which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: `malloc(15gb)` will *automatically* obtain huge pages. That's how it works. There is no benefit to "static allocating" them because the majority of the cost in the allocation is manipulating the current process's vma/page tables, which would happen if you were mapping pre-allocated shared memory objects too.

Comment: I don't think so. According to this article [link](http://lwn.net/Articles/375096/) you must use an interface.

Comment: don't cast the return of `malloc`, in particular `void*` is what it is supposed to return anyhow. Don't use the oldish `shmat` interfaces if you can avoid it but the modern `shmopen`. It is much easier to use and has less restrictions. But do so only if you want to *share* a segment between different processes. There is not much point in using it otherwise, use `mmap` directly to map an anonymous segment.

Comment: If you can cite a source on malloc() automatically obtaining huge pages without transparent huge paging enabled I'd be very interested to read it.

Comment: I'm assuming you have transparent huge pages enabled. Otherwise, no, `malloc` will not obtain them. Why would you turn transparent huge pages off?

Comment: Those are transparent huge pages which must be enabled within the Kernel. The method I'm using doesn't use transparent pages. Research has shown that greater performance benefits can come from using statically allocated huge pages as the transparent paging kernel code is not optimized.

Comment: What you're trying to do sounds like it's equivalent, but doing the "transparent" usage of huge pages in userspace at the `malloc` level rather than in kernelspace. I'm not sure if it will buy you any performance, but I doubt it will be more than 1-3% even if it does. Optimizing the code in kernelspace and putting userspace hackery for huge page support behind us would be a lot more productive, I think.

Comment: I have no doubt the performance impact will be small however when applications such as this one take 8 days to run 1-3% can equate to significant time. Optimizing the Kernel code would be the ideal solution but this hack is just something quick to see an immediate change.

Comment: On 2.6.32 and newer kernels you can use `mmap()` with `MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_HUGETLB` to directly obtain memory backed by huge pages. `malloc()` uses `mmap()` with `MAP_ANONYMOUS` for large allocations so it needs transparent huge pages enabled. You also said that your program is highly concurrent. Then you might also look into SMP- and NUMA-aware allocators like `ptmalloc` and `tcmalloc` - you might get better performance margin than just utilising huge pages.